# ¿Porqué en Github Pages mi proyecto no carga las fuentes que tengo en mi repositorio?

Tags: css, github, fuentes, github-pages

Estoy creando un proyecto web con unas fuentes en específico... fuentes que descargué e incluí en mi proyecto en una carpeta

[image: En mi proyecto hay una carpeta específicamente para las fuentes]

son archivos ttf, y en mi css los tengo enlazados de la siguiente manera

[image: Fuente enlazada]

En mi computadora con live server se visualiza correctamente pero en mi repositorio de GitHub al subirlo en Github Pages pese a estar igual, no se aplica la fuente y me muestra un problema en la consola, cosa que en mi máquina local no me muestra ni un solo error
[image: Problema de la imagen 404]

Intenté cambiar la ubicación de la carpeta de Fonts incluyéndola en la carpeta de Styles (cambié la dirección de la nueva ubicación en la hoja css) pero sigue sin funcionar, tengo el mismo problema con una imagen pero ahora solo me interesa solucionar las fuentes

Comment: usa url relativas, quita el `/` del inicio de la ruta, luego subes un nivel en la ruta con `../`. te deberia quedar como `src: url(../Fonts/ozda/ozda.ttf);`

Comment: Usa texto en lugar de imágenes para colocar tu código. Lee el [tour] y [ask].